# How to make AutoHotKey ignore a hotstring when it is preceded by a period?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotKey script that expands abbreviations into full words or phrases, but I ran into a problem today.  I wanted to add `org` as a hotstring for "organization", but realized that when typing webpages like `wikipedia.org` it would put `wikipedia.organization`.  My thought was to just add a line like

```
::.org:: return
```

so it kicks out of the script if I'm writing a .org address, but org by itself would still work.  However, the above attempt does not work (still outputs "organization").  I'm guessing that because <kbd>.</kbd> is part of the AHK code it is not seeing it as part of the hotstring.  I thought I could escape it by putting the normal escape character <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) but that didn't work either.

Searching the AHK documentation has not yielded anything useful, mostly because "dot" and "period" both refer to topics other than punctuation, so not a useful search term.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid conflicts altogether & make all your hotstrings start with an unusual character instead? I use nc*something* or kb*something*, depending on what 'family' it is*.
Intentionally letters that never start a word in English.
You could even use §*something* etc. though common symbols like $ wouldn't work.

Even a single letter like 'k' for 'keyboard' giving you `kcom` for a simple structure. [My nc is for 'notecard' ie an info-dump that used to be copy-paste, kb is 'keyboard'.]

*though, tbh, I don't use it to just expand single words much of the time, so I'm still saving a fair bit of typing even adding two chars.

Comment: All my shortcuts are 2-4 characters long, with the intent being speed of use and reduction in typing for phrases I use all the time. (`org` will actually be a much longer phrase than I listed, but it's irrelevant to the question.) I feel like adding in a prefix to all the shortcuts would partially defeat that purpose.  I'll just use a different shortcut if I can't figure this out, it just seemed like it should have been an easy fix but doesn't seem to work. Asked here more for education/solving the "riddle" than because this is has broken my process.

Comment: idk AHK, I use a different structure, but just stick a `k` in front of them, one letter saves many conflicts. Answer edited probably in the time you were typing. A period is often itself a trigger for the replacement, so I doubt you could avoid it. My stucture uses a space or punctuation to trigger.

Comment: Yeah, it will come down to a fix like that if I don't figure out what's wrong.  I'm by no means a genius at AHK, but I use it often enough I thought I could solve this, so it bugs me that it doesn't do what I expect in this case.

Comment: I think punctuation is going to get you every time. I've been using this structure a long, long time & just learned to avoid the obvious pitfalls of a trigger that could potentially be a 'word'

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work myself, but perhaps you could use one of the regex hotstring libraries (e.g. [RegExHotstrings](https://www.computoredge.com/AutoHotkey/Free_AutoHotkey_Scripts_and_Apps_for_Learning_and_Generating_Ideas.html#RegExHotstrings) or [RegEx Dynamic Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/114764-regex-dynamic-hotstrings/)) to only match `org` and not `.org`.

The regex would be something like `^(?!\.)org`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Apparently <kbd>.</kbd> is one of AHK's "Ending Characters", like <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (characters which denote the end of the hotstring and trigger the appropriate response).  Apparently, this means that writing `wikipedia.org` did not trigger the `.org` section that should have exited the script because it treated it as 2 inputs, `wikipedia` and `org`, thus triggering the replacement of `org`.  The solution was the following:

```
#Hotstring B0
:?:.org:: 
return
#Hotstring B
```

As I understand it, the `:?:` notation means that the hotstring can appear as part of another word, allowing it to see the <kbd>.</kbd> as part of both `wikipedia` and `org`, in which case the entirety of `.org` triggers the exiting of the script.  The `#Hotstring B0` / `#Hotstring B` wrappers prevent it from backspacing over the `.org` characters before quitting.  This code needs to be above the other hotstrings in the script so the `return` statement can exit the script before the other `org` hotstring executes.